# peer not authenticated com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: peer not authenticated

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm experiencing a gradle sync error "Error:Cause: peer not authenticated"

The problem seems to be related to accessing parse.com libraries, the detailed log is attached.

I have tried 
 1. delete .gradle folder and let android studio regenerate, then restarted computer
 2. deleting settings.gradle and let android studio regenerate
 3. reverting to the older version of the project that was working before (but not working anymore now)

same error is generated when I ran it second time

However, when I tried the example project from android studio (without parse.com usage), the gradle sync was completed successfully so it seems to be a parse.com access issue definitely

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ParseStarterProject:classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:180)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:467)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.defineScriptHandlerClassScope(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:146)
    at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.applyPlugins(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:58)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:128)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+.
Required by:
    GroceryRunnerNative:ParseStarterProject:unspecified
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainAdapter.resolve(RepositoryChainAdapter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.projectmodule.ProjectDependencyResolver.resolve(ProjectDependencyResolver.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DependencySubstitutionResolver.resolve(DependencySubstitutionResolver.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:880)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveDependencyGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:125)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:253)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:465)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.process(DynamicVersionResolver.java:362)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:347)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:66)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.parse.tools:gradle.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ChainedVersionLister$1.visit(ChainedVersionLister.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.listVersionsForAllPatterns(ExternalResourceResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.doListModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:127)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.access$100(ExternalResourceResolver.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:410)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$1.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:242)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:280)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.listModuleVersions(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:80)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.parse.com/repo/com/parse/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1.visit(MavenVersionLister.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ChainedVersionLister$1.visit(ChainedVersionLister.java:47)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://maven.parse.com/repo/com/parse/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.parseMavenMetadataInfo(MavenMetadataLoader.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:47)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:111)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:87)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:78)
    ... 111 more
2016-05-28 22:02:11,252 [ 841000]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: peer not authenticated 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cause: peer not authenticated
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:438)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)

2016-05-28 22:02:11,253 [ 841001]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-05-28 22:02:11,253 [ 841001]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause: peer not authenticated

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-05-28 22:02:11,253 [ 841001]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'GroceryRunnerNative' failed: Cause: peer not authenticated

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-05-28 22:02:11,417 [ 841165]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-28 22:02:11,421 [ 841169]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-28 22:02:11,431 [ 841179]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-28 22:02:11,432 [ 841180]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-05-28 22:02:13,411 [ 843159]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
2016-05-28 22:02:14,959 [ 844707]   INFO - figurations.GeneralCommandLine - Cannot run program "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Git Shell.lnk" (in directory "C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\GitHub\Favourama\GroceryRunnerNative"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Git Shell.lnk" (in directory "C:\Users\Jeremy\Documents\GitHub\Favourama\GroceryRunnerNative"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.startProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:306)
    at com.intellij.execution.configurations.GeneralCommandLine.createProcess(GeneralCommandLine.java:292)
    at git4idea.commands.GitTextHandler.createProcess(GitTextHandler.java:125)
    at git4idea.commands.GitTextHandler.startProcess(GitTextHandler.java:57)
    at git4idea.commands.GitHandler.start(GitHandler.java:481)
    at git4idea.commands.GitHandler.runInCurrentThread(GitHandler.java:834)
    at git4idea.commands.GitSimpleHandler.run(GitSimpleHandler.java:239)
    at git4idea.status.GitOldChangesCollector.updateIndex(GitOldChangesCollector.java:139)
    at git4idea.status.GitOldChangesCollector.<init>(GitOldChangesCollector.java:128)
    at git4idea.status.GitOldChangesCollector.collect(GitOldChangesCollector.java:109)
    at git4idea.status.GitChangeProvider.getChanges(GitChangeProvider.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.actualUpdate(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:734)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.iterateScopes(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:651)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.updateImmediately(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:526)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl.access$1200(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManagerImpl$ActualUpdater.run(ChangeListManagerImpl.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.UpdateRequestsQueue$MyRunnable.run(UpdateRequestsQueue.java:260)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually occurring for some other developers using parse. I think the maven repo for parse gradle tool has a different permission now, and I would suggest you to stop using the parse gradle tool, use googles instead:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
```

Also, try download the Parse SDK locally and use that, should be safer that way.

Hope this helps :-)